# VBA EXCEL - Small code optimization for on-worksheet open macro

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I am looking to speed up an on-worksheet open macro I have in excel.

Every time the worksheet is opened, I would like it to autofit x rows and then hide any rows that have a 0 in it.

The macro works fine, but I think there must be a better/faster way to hide all relevant rows. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Rows("14:859").EntireRow.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("O1:O859").Cells
        If c.Value = "0" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Const LAST_ROW = 859
  Const CL = 15             'O column
  Const RO = 14
  Const HIDE_ROWS = True    'or False

  Dim ur As Variant, hr As Range, R As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Rows(RO & ":" & LAST_ROW).EntireRow.AutoFit

  ur = Range(Cells(1, CL), Cells(LAST_ROW, CL))
  For R = 1 To LAST_ROW
    If Len(ur(R, 1)) = 0 Then Exit For
    If ur(R, 1) = 0 Then
        If hr Is Nothing Then Set hr = Cells(R, 1) Else: Set hr = Union(hr, Cells(R, 1))
    End If
  Next
  hr.EntireRow.Hidden = HIDE_ROWS

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a debug error at the following line:         If ur(r, c) = "0" Then

Comment: What is the first cell and last cell on your sheet?

Comment: The core filter is from cell o1:o859

Comment: I made some changes (issue should be fixed as well). I customized it to search column O only; I also tested it on a small data set. Please try it again and accept the answer if it works, and let me know if it's faster than the initial one, if possible

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you. It works much faster now.